# How to keep square brackets and text contained while removing everything else

Tags: regex

I have this string **$183,361 [10.00 FTE]**.

I want to trim it to only keep **[10.00 FTE]**

I have only been able to remove the square brackets with `/\[(.*?)\]/`.

This is how I am displaying the string on screen

```
<>
    {rowData.Q1.replace(*Regex*, "")}
</>
```

What regex expression will help with getting the output I want?

Comment: What is the programming language/environment?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using JavaScript here, I would just use string `match()` with a capture group:

```js
var input = "$183,361 [10.00 FTE]";
var output = input.match(/\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)? (\[.*?\])/)[1];
console.log(output);
```

If you don't insist on the bracketed term being preceded by a dollar amount, then simplify the regex pattern to `\[.*?\]` and use this version:

```js
var input = "$183,361 [10.00 FTE]";
var output = input.match(/\[.*?\]/)[0];
console.log(output);
```